# \if\subject\subjectold returns false even though subject and subjectold should be the same

Tags: macros, conditionals

I am currently working with conditionals and I am currently stuck because even though the conditional argument should not be used (e.g. \subject should be "B", \subjectold  and \bio too), the test below returns false. Why does it do that and is there any way I could test this successfully.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}

\def\bio{B}
\def\math{M}
\begin{document}

%defining command subject
\newcommand{\subject}[0]{\bio}
\let\subjectold\subject
\renewcommand{\subject}[1][]{\bio
\if%if the subject is math use the optional argument
\subjectold\math #1
\fi}

%This test returns false
\if\subject\subjectold
    True
\else
    False
\fi
%Also returns false
\if\subject\bio
    True
\else
    False
\fi
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\if\subject` compares the first twonon expandable  tokens in the expansion of `\subject` so it would be true for `aardvarks`

Comment: Probably a better idea to use say the macros in `etoolbox` to compare strings. As David mentions `\if` does not do what you think.

Comment: Fixed the code and thank you for you answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}

\def\bio{B}
\def\math{M}
```

If you use `\newcommand` rather than `\def` you would be warned about over-writing core latex commands like `\math`.

```
\begin{document}

%defining command subject
\newcommand{\subject}[0]{\bio}
\let\subjectold\subject
\renewcommand{\subject}[1][]{\bio
```

This makes `\subject` into a non expandable command that needs to look ahead for `[`

```
\if%if the subject is math use the optional argument
\oldsubject\math #1
```

`\if\oldsubject`  would compare the first two non expandable tokens in the expansion  of `\oldsubject`  but as there is only one token it compares B with M

```
\fi}

%This test returns false
\if\subject\subjectold
```

This is comparing the first two non expandable tokens in `\subject` which are essentially arbitrary internal assignments during the lookahead for `[` while skipping over spaces.

to compare `\subject` against `\subjectold` you would need `\ifx` but a command with optional arguments is never ifx equal to one without.

```
    True
\else
    False
\fi
%Also returns false
```

As above `\if\subject` does nothing meaningful.

```
\if\subject\bio
    True
\else
    False
\fi
\end{document}#
```